# apply values of inputs to all its td innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, innerhtml, html-table

is it possible to change the innerhtml of all the td when it has the input inside, i mean to take the input's value and apply it to it's td innerhtml, for example, here's the table and its input inside:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input value="test" /></td>
  <td>123</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

to change it smth into this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>123</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

for all of the td and input values without applying id's and classes?! please pay attention that td innerhtml didnt change :) thank you all for the help! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty easy.

Name your table first (to find it easily).

```
<table id="the_table">
 <tr>
  <td><input value="test" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$('#the_table td input[type="text"]').each(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent('td').html(val);
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/arebep).

#### Explanation:

1. find all inputs that are within `<td>` that are in this certain table.
2. for each input:

   2.1 retrieve value from the input

   2.2 find first parent of the input that is a `<td>` tag and set its `innerHTML` to that value

Comment: got one more problem! what if there are input whose types are: hidden, and i need to use just the inputs whose type is text?! 3 min left, will accept ur answer, no worries ))

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
$('table td:has(:input:only-child)').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(':input', this).val());
});
```

It assumes there only is an `input` in the `td`. If that is not the case, then remove `:only-child`.

**Explanation of `table td:has(:input:only-child)`**

It says, take any `td` within a `table`, which has an `input` as the only child.

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/eydtw/

**Update: take the `input` which is not `hidden`.**

```
$('table td:has(input[type!="hidden"])').each(function () {
    $(this).html($('input[type!="hidden"]', this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eydtw/1/

**or: take the `input` which is `text`.**

```
$('table td:has(input:text)').each(function () {
    $(this).html($('input:text', this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eydtw/3/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each($('table td'),function(){

    if($(this).children().length !=0)
    {

        var temp = $($(this).children()[0]).val();
        $(this).html(temp);

    }

})
```