# exporting data entered into textboxes to excel in the form of table

Tags: export-to-excel, buttonclick

Hello everyone i am designing a web page that contains many textboxes and a button.The function of that button is to export whatever written in the textbox to an excel file.Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting Question...

First of All, you should provide more details and include more relevant tags.

Solution 1:

Step 1: Get the `Input` values as content of `<TD>`.
[apply-values-of-inputs-to-all-its-td-innerhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768847/apply-values-of-inputs-to-all-its-td-innerhtml)

Step 2: Export the content of table to the excel.
[export-html-table-to-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364107/export-html-table-to-excel-using-asp-net/9810842#9810842)

Solution 2:
You can use the [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx)